# Load balancer or IIS - which one is causing my urls to be case sensitive

Tags: asp.net, iis, load-balancing, cisco, thinktecture-ident-server

We have two Windows 2008 R2 serveres set up with a Cisco Ace-30 load balancer, and a few MVC and WebForms apps (.net 4.5 and 4.5.1) with federated authentication (thinktecture). The load balancer is configured with ssl, but the traffic from load balancer to web servers is on http. The problem I'm trying to solve is that the part of the url is case sensitive. Take this urls:

- https://my-server.temp.net/MyApp/ (working)
- https://my-SERVER.temp.net/MyApp/ (working)
- https://my-SERVER.temp.net/MyApp/DEfault.AsPX (working)
- https://my-server.temp.net/myapp/ (not-working, that is no response)

In the load balancer, I've disabled the default case sensitivity, and from what I've read there's no such setting in IIS. I've tried creating a static website (no auth) and this works as expected:

- https://my-server.temp.net/StaticSITE/ (working)
- https://my-server.temp.net/staticsite/ (working)

I've also tried setting up a url rewrite rule, and once that rule is applied the the timeout appear. My guess is that it is IIS that rewrites the incomming http request to a new http request, and the load balancer does not recognize its the https request that has been modified. But I'm guessing and beyond my comfort zone here.

So now I'm a bit confused and unsure what's causing the url to be case sensitive. Is it:

- The load balancer
- IIS
- The authentication
- Something else

I would be really happy for any ideas or debugging tips

Thanks

Larsi

Comment: Is it really too hard to capture some network packets and see where the requests go? That should easily tell you where is the problem, and then you can focus on that spot. IIS is highly configurable, so it is rather difficult to draw a conclusion saying "there's no such setting in IIS". For example, a badly-written URL rewrite rule can be case-sensitive and bite you badly too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, I figured out the problem (or atleast a solution). The IIS was sending a redirect and that redirect was to a http address.

So when we configured the load balancer to redirect http to https everything works as expected. My guess is that the federation was causing the IIS to do an extra redirect when the casing was not correct, but that's just a thought.

Anyway - http to https redirect on load balancer solved it.

Larsi